# Ejabberd Redis + MySql database combination

Tags: mysql, redis, ejabberd, riak, mnesia

I am newbie to the Ejabberd so I am still exploring all the possibilities and possible setups for chat server.

From the documentation I have seen that Ejabberd supports Redis database for transient data, user session I suppose...

I was wondering has anyone had any experience using Redis for storing transient data and then MySql for the rest of the data? Will this setup be beneficial comparing to Mnesia + MySql one? Maybe Redis + Riak is even better setup?

Just looking for some general opinions since I am a newcomer in this area...

Answer (score 3):

Full disclosure: I work for [Basho](http://basho.com), the maintainers of Riak, so I have a clear preference here.

Looking at the [source of Ejabberd](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd), I see it's written in Erlang as well, which is optimized as a distributed system. Their [architecture diagram](http://docs.ejabberd.im/images/architect/ejabberd_large_scale.pdf) specifically shows Riak as a NoSQL backend. Redis is often paired with Riak due to its simple retrieval and key/value design. If scale is a concern on the transient side as well, you could use Riak's in-memory backend alongside the disk-based backend for durable data ([more on backends here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/planning/backends/)).

Riak is designed for scaling, so if you anticipate growth beyond a single server's worth of CPU, memory or storage, then it's perfect. If you do not anticipate this growth, then Riak may be overkill. For more on when to use it, [read this](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/theory/why-riak/).

Comment: Thanks for the insight, it is definitely going to be helpful!